# Can't get Babylon off Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, babylon

Babylon has taken over my computer.  After hours, I managed to get rid of it on IE and Firefox, but nothing I do works for Chrome.  I have made google my default browser in settings and followed the advice of several forums and help services, but nothing works.  I am using a pc with windows 7 and I am not very computer tech savvy.  Thanks

Comment: Here's a great video breakdown on how to remove Babylon from Chrome in 2013 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReN87NGfxng

Comment: WTH is babylon and how did it get to your computer?

Answer (score 6):

To remove Babylon (or anything else that has taken over Google Chrome), doing the following should suffice:

1. Go to `chrome://chrome/settings/startup` and remove all related pages.

   This is done by clicking the `X` at the right of the entry.
2. Go to `chrome://chrome/extensions/` and remove all related extensions.

   This is done by hovering over the entry and clicking the trash can icon when it appears.
3. Go to `chrome://chrome/settings/searchEngines` and select a proper default search.

   This is done by hovering over the desired search engine (normally `Google`, at the very top of the first list) and clicking `Make default`.

If anything survives, you'll need a malware scanner like [MBAM](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) (easy) or [HiJackThis](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hjt/) (advanced).

For the specific case of Babylon, there are a number of [step-by-step videos on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?q=babylon%20chrome%20uninstall) that might help.

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove Babylon from your Google Chrome Browser:

**Remove Babylon Features:**

Change Homepage

1. Open Google Chrome, click on the "Customize and control Google Chrome " icon by the right side of the address bar; click on Settings:
2. Inside Settings under "On startup", choose the option "Open a specific page or set of pages."
3. Click on "Set pages" and delete Babylon's page from the list by clicking the small "x" icon beside it.

**Remove Search Provider:**

In order to change the Search Engine in Google Chrome, please follow the instructions below:

1. Open Google Chrome, click on the "Customize and control Google Chrome " icon by the right side of the address bar
2. Click on Settings > Under "Search" click on "Manage search engines...":
3. If you see Babylon Search as default, please click on a different option (Google, Bing etc.).
   Make it default, then remove Babylon by clicking the small 'x'.

**Remove Search from New Tab:**

1. Open Google Chrome, click on the "Customize and control Google Chrome " icon on the right side of the address bar:
2. Go to Tools > Extensions.
3. Remove any Babylon extension (Translator, Toolbar Etc...) from the list by clicking on the small trash bin icon that will appear when you point the cursor over it.

Comment: You just repeated what Dennis said and linked to a known hostile malicious website. Why?

Comment: @Ramhound: I thought Dennis only mentioned the middle bit. Malicious ?Thats where I got the instructions from..i'm confused

Comment: Babylon is a hostile malicious add-on that roots itself into every system it can automatically and without intervention.  Lets not give them any more page hits then required to do so.  If you remove the link to their website I will remove the downvote, lets not give Babylon anymore page hits, then we already have.

Comment: @Ramhound: I needed to get rid of Babylon, a friend sent me the link, I followed the instructions...it worked, so I had a look here & I gave the complete removal instructions, as I thought it would help

Comment: @Ramhound - No problem, but why would they supply accurate instructions for removal then, thats why i'm confused...Ive been having problems for ages with Babylon

Comment: @Ramhound: Edited out

Comment: Because if they didn't they would be blacklisted by security vendors.  Right now there application is defined as "annoying"

Comment: @Ramhound - There instructions worked thats why I didnt understand, Thx for clarifying though :)

Answer (score 0):

Open up chrome and go to the little three bars for settings. Open Settings > Extensions > Click the trash bin > Your done! However you might have to set your search engine again. Same thing go to settings > Scroll down to search > select google or whatever engine you use.

Then go to PC control panel, find babylon search or delta search in your program list and remove it.
Hope this helped a little.

I also suggest you check this [babylon toolbar removal](http://www.yac.mx/en/guides/browser-hijacker-removal/20130814-how-to-remove-babylon-search-toolbar-through-isafe-virus-removal-tool.html) guide if you still not can not get rid of it completely.